# NetUserChangePassword 1351 error issue and NetUserSetInfo(with DPAPI) inquiry

Tags: c++, windows, change-password, netapi32

This is a Windows Login UI dll project made in C++.

A problem occurs if you forcefully change the password using NetUserSetInfo and then log in.

An error occurs in a program that encrypts and decrypts using DPAPI.

I thought there would be no problem if I changed NetUserSetInfo 1003 to NetUserChangePassword.

Even when using it before logging in, error 1351 occurs.

I want to know why the error occurs and how to work around it.

Run CMD on the login screen and confirm password change using NetUserSetInfo.

Run CMD on the log screen and check that error 1351 has occurred using NetUserChangePassword.

I searched to know the inside of NetUserSetInfo and NetUserChangePassword functions.

- https://doxygen.reactos.org/d2/d5b/dll_2win32_2netapi32_2user_8c_source.html#l03975
- https://doxygen.reactos.org/d2/d5b/dll_2win32_2netapi32_2user_8c_source.html#l02399

Find out why encryption and decryption is not possible with SetInfo but possible with ChangePassword.

- https://blogs.msmvps.com/alunj/2006/11/07/changepassword-versus-setpassword/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.